# Installing a Web Browser in Linux Server

Tags: server, software-recommendation

I have a website which is being hosted by a Linux Server. I can access my files of my website using SSH. I was thinking if it is possible to install a web browser into my linux server so that I can browse websites in it.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to do here.

If that is possible, can you show me how to do it.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of your question, I think you want a visual browser in linux server.  [there are other several](http://www.helgefjell.de/browser.php) browsers for linux. 
The easiest one would be

```
w3m -v http://www.google.com
```

There is another similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24731/minimum-to-install-for-a-visual-web-browser-in-ubuntu-server).

Answer (score 1):

If you have only SSH access to your server, I'm not sure if a graphical browser would work without installing Xorg on server side, as the packages pull Xorg as a dependency, however you could try to install a Web-Browser from a tar.gz file and forward X over SSH by using `ssh -x`.

If you just want a command line browser, you should install links.

Comment: The name of the command line browser you are thinking of is "lynx."

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 links is based on the source code of lynx, but it's not the same

Comment: Oh ok, my bad then.

Comment: Using lynx is also possible, but links is newer and I don't know if lynx is still maintained.

Answer (score 0):

If you have administrative privileges on the system, and you know what package manager it uses, you can simply install the browser like you normally would. However, I suspect you only have access to a subset of the files.

In that case, take a look at http://portablelinuxapps.org/. They have builds of Firefox and Chromium that run out of a local directory. All you need to do is drop their files on the target computer and run the executable inside, independent of the installed packages on the system.

You may encounter problems giving the executable the necessary permissions to run; you ability to run code from your folders is set by the web server's administrative policies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that no one ever mentionned Lynx. I used it since I started web developement.

According to Wikipédia : "Lynx is a highly configurable text-based web browser for use on cursor-addressable character cell terminals. It is the oldest web browser currently in general use and development, having started in 1992 and as of 2013, 21 years later, still in use and development."

You can install it with `sudo apt-get install lynx`. Start it with `lynx nameofthewebsite` and you are done !

Comment: You should read other answeers and comments before saying that no one has mentioned lynx!

Comment: And you should know that when I posted it, the comment wasn't posted yet.

Comment: The name of the command line browser you are thinking of is "lynx." – BryceAtNetwork23 Mar 13 at 15:25!!!!!!!! Using lynx is also possible, but links is newer and I don't know if lynx is still maintained. – FSMaxB Mar 13 at 15:30 !!!!!!!!!!! And your answer: answered Mar 13 at 15:43!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I started to writing around 15:00. But I posted it around 15:45.

Comment: Ok that's comprehensible. I apologize, I didn't mean to be so offensive.